# Mysql get the records within 90 days

Tags: php, mysql, select, date-range

I have a table and I have to get the records that have their certify_date in next 90 days range. I have tried the following but it gives me last 90 days records

```
SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, recertificationdate
FROM mytbl 
WHERE certify_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW() 
ORDER by createdon DESC
```

Comment: Don't you want `NOW()` and `DATE_ADD` instead?

Comment: it shows 0 records,

Comment: Please post sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data. If that returns 0 records, then you have no records that are within the next 90 days.

Comment: @baig772 Make sure you swap the order. with `BETWEEN`, the later date has to be second.

Comment: @Barmar can you please make the query?

Comment: `WHERE certify_date BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))`

Comment: @Barmar told you the same thing I did 2 hours ago.